# what is "Out went.."?

Tags: meaning, sentence

Context

The Japanese government rushed to modernise and industrialise. ... Out went kimonos, in came business suits and top hats.

Comment: 'In came' and 'out went' are usually used for elective changes in society, corporations etc. 'Out went the silent movie.' 'In came the mini skirt.' Here, it's the Japanese government electing to change its image.

Answer (score 1):

"Out went kimonos" means that  people stopped wearing kimonos. It could be considered as short for "went out *of fashion*". Similarly, "came in" could be considered as short for "came in *to fashion*".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are wondering about the special word order with "out" before the verb.
The normal word order is:  The bear came out of its den.

When you place "out" before the verb as in "Out came the bear of its den" the sentence gets a lot of dynamics. Everything that is out of the normal word order automatically catches the attention and has a special effect.

Comment: I think you mean *Out of its den came the bear* ...?

Comment: I think your formulation is better.

Comment: It's because you have to front the whole PP not just the head P ;)